# Using date range to alter histogram range in server R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, date-range

I'm trying to use a date range function to alter the data used to display a histogram in R Shiny. I have some incomplete code as I cant figure out how to code this in the server function. see bellow for a minimal code example and where I think some code should go. :

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(123)


N<- 500
M<-56

EF<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
WM<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=20,sd=3), N, M)
DP<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=25,sd=3), N, M)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(code(strong("Measures"), style = "color:black")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      strong("Tools:"),
      selectInput("Test", 
                  label = "Choose a measure to display",
                  choices = c("EF", 
                              "WM",
                              "DP"
                  ),
                  selected = "EF"),

      dateRangeInput("DateRange", label= "Date Range:", start ="2018-01-01", end = "2018-02-25")),
    mainPanel(
      code(strong("Study Readout")),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    ))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  filterData <- reactive({
      x    <- switch(input$Test, 
                     "EF" = EF,
                     "WM" = WM, 
                     "DP" = DP)
      return(x)

  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <-filterData()

    DateRange <- #????

      hist(x, #????)
  })
}


# Run that shit ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just subset your vector `x` according to the date range, comment out the conversion to `POSIXct` and fill the blanks like this.

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(123)

N<-500
M<-56

EF<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
WM<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=20,sd=3), N, M)
DP<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=25,sd=3), N, M)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
#Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(code(strong("Measures"), style = "color:black")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      strong("Tools:"),
      selectInput("Test", 
                  label = "Choose a measure to display",
                  choices = c("EF", 
                              "WM",
                              "DP"
                  ),
                  selected = "EF"),

      dateRangeInput("DateRange", label= "Date Range:", start ="2018-01-01", end = "2018-02-25")),
    mainPanel(
      code(strong("Study Readout")),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  filterData <- reactive({
    x    <- switch(input$Test, 
                   "EF" = EF,
                   "WM" = WM, 
                   "DP" = DP)
    return(x)

  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <-filterData()
    hist(x[Date >= min(input$DateRange) & Date <= max(input$DateRange)])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```